# Is it possible to figure out if a specific field has been updated, in a Sql Server Trigger?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, onupdate

If I have a simple table and I want to do something (say .. execute a stored procedure) when a column (and I know the column I wish to look for) has changed.

Is this possible?

Version: SQL Server 2008 R2.

Example table :-

```
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
Name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
Age TINYINT NOT NULL
HairColour TINYINT NOT NULL
```

So .. if the content of the *Name* field changes, then I will execute stored procedure 'Foo'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_updateName ON YOUR_TABLE

FOR UPDATE AS

  IF NOT UPDATE(Name) 
  BEGIN

     RETURN

  END

  EXEC foo
```

This trigger would automatically be executed whenever we updated one/more records in YOUR_TABLE. The "UPDATE" function is used to check whether or not the "Name" field has been updated by an "UPDATE" query that executed the "trig_updateAuthor" trigger. If field hasn't, then the trigger returns control to SQL server.

Comment: Poines - sauceofawesome ! Now, the thing that KILLS me with triggers (read: I suck at triggers) is that if *any/one-or-more* of the rows that were effected, in the trigger results, this the stored proc will run. I can never get my head around triggers + multiple results/rows and having to fire off logic per row. i keep thinking it's one trigger per row *blush* .. I'm guessing i'll need an evil cursor to call stored procs per row... :(

Comment: @Pure.Krome: Depends on what you want to do in the stored procedure.  Maybe that should addressed in a separate question?

Comment: Yep - i was only thinking out aloud .. definitely not extending this question.